# How to understand these implementations of spinlocks?

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, programming-languages, computer-science

I have some difficulty understanding spin locks from Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott. Appreciate if you could explain them more clear. Thanks.

1. > While all of these algorithms are historically important, a practical
   >   spin lock needs to run in constant time and space, and for this one
   >   needs an atomic instruction that does more than load or store.
   >   Beginning in the 1960s, hardware designers began to equip their
   >   processors with instructions that  read, modify, and write a memory
   >   location as a single atomic operation .  The simplest such instruction
   >   is known as `test_and_set`. It sets a Boolean variable to true and
   >   returns an  indication of whether the variable was previously false.
   >   Given test_and_set, acquiring a spin lock is almost trivial:
   >
   > ```
   > while not test_and_set(L)
   >     –– nothing –– spin
   > ```

   What does the value of `L` mean?

   Does `test_and_set(L)` return false if and only if `L` is true?

   Why does it work as a spin lock?
2. > In practice, embedding **test_and_set** in a loop tends to result in
   >   unacceptable amounts of communication on a multicore or multiprocessor
   >   machine, as the cache coherence mechanism attempts to reconcile writes
   >   by multiple cores attempting to acquire the lock. This overdemand for
   >   hardware resources is known as contention, and is a major obstacle to
   >   good performance on large machines.
   >
   > To reduce contention, the writers of synchronization libraries often
   >   employ a **test-and-test_and_set lock**, which spins with ordinary reads
   >   (satisﬁed by the cache) until it appears that the lock is free (see
   >   Figure 13.8). When a thread releases a lock there still tends to be a
   >   ﬂurry of bus or interconnect activity as waiting threads perform their
   >   test_and_sets, but at least this activity happens only at the
   >   boundaries of critical sections. On a large machine, contention can be
   >   further reduced by implementing a backoff strategy, in which a thread
   >   that is unsuccessful in attempting to acquire a lock waits for a while
   >   before trying again.
   >
   > ```
   > type lock = Boolean := false;
   > procedure acquire lock(ref L : lock)
   >     while not test and set(L)
   >         while L
   >             –– nothing –– spin
   > procedure release lock(ref L : lock)
   >     L := false
   > ```
   >
   > Figure 13.8 A simple test-and-test_and_set lock. Waiting processes
   >   spin with ordinary read  (load) instructions until the lock appears to
   >   be free, then use test_and_set to acquire it. The very ﬁrst access is
   >   a test_and_set, for speed in the common (no competition) case.

   Does "ordinary read  (load) instructions" refer to the instruction
   of reading `L` in `while L`?

   How does this way work better than the first one?

Answer (score 3):

> What does the value of L mean?

`L` is set to 0 when the lock is free and to 1 if the lock is locked by someone.

> Does test_and_set(L) return false if and only if L is true?

Yes, it is explicitely described in the citation you refer to: "returns an indication of whether the variable was previously false".

> Why does it work as a spin lock?

It satisfies the invariant for variable `L` described above.

> Does "ordinary read (load) instructions" refer to the instruction of reading L in while L?

Yes.

> How does this way work better than the first one?

Checking that `L` is 0 by "ordinary read" instruction involves less "amounts of communication on a multicore or multiprocessor machine" than by using `test_and_set` instruction. So, when one core spins on the locked lock, other cores are less affected.